# How to run different cloud functions for seperate apps in the same Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

For example, if I wanted to use the functions.auth.user().onUserCreate() trigger, is there any way to make it trigger different functions for different apps that are all in the same Firebase project? Is the only way to fix this to create separate Firebase projects for each app? The issue with that is that I need them to access the same database.

Comment: Firebase Auth users are shared between all apps within a project -- there is no separating them by "app." It's hard to know what advice to give you without additional details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would like to trigger a different cloud function depending on which app the user registers from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to know in a Cloud Functions trigger which app a user used when they created their account.  Firebase Auth accounts don't have a sense of "ownership" with respect to multiple apps per project.  All apps in a project share the same users with the same permissions.

What you can do instead is have each app write something unique in your database after the account was created, then use that to determine what that user should do later on.  Either that, or use different projects if your apps don't actually need to share the same set of users.

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility that I think that might help you is organizing your Cloud Functions in different files, which will be then loaded per project. So, for example, in your `Project Alpha`, it will run the Cloud Functions from the `foo.js` file, while in the `Project Beta`, it will run the functions from the `bar.js` and the same logic for other projects and Cloud Functions.

This way, even though all users are sharing the same database, it will trigger the function based in the file that you requiring in your application. You can check for tips in organizing your Cloud Functions in multiple files and calling them individually, in this official documentation here:

- [Organize Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions)

I believe this way might work for you, so, I would recommend you to check the documentation and give it a try splitting the functions in multiple files and calling each specific files, on their specific applications only.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the info on organizing functions. I ended up using Doug Stevensons answer